Can I do anything for my squash vine that lost its leaves?
This year I set myself up a grow tent for for the first time.  My first group of seedlings were all luffa gourd. I sowed the seeds into soil blocks at the very end of February, and they lived in the tent at a steady 80°F / 27°C, ~75% RH.  Each one grew into a 3-4 ft. vine with leaves.
I transplanted them into the ground after 6 weeks in the tent, last Thursday.  The weather outdoors is 45°F / 7°C at night and 65°F / 18°C during the day, and unusually rainy.  It rained over 2 inches the day I planted them. And on top of that, I neglected to harden them.  Yeah.
All of the vines except two have lost all of their leaves.  But the vines themselves still look healthy.
My question is, at this point what can I do to help my patients?  I have removed all of the obviously dead leaves (leaving all but 2 of my 12 vines completely bare).  Should I cut the vines shorter?  Should I fertilize them?  Should I appreciate what they have taught me and get something else in this bed?




I would do nothing now.
Eventually you can build a temporary green house if weather will remain cold, so put around a plastic sheet or a tissue around the plant, and maybe protect the soil with more hay, but it seems you already have enough.
Then I would wait. No pruning, not removing leaves. I would wait until I see real growths. Only in such phase you can decide visually what to keep. Now it may be a bet. But also after that, I would prune only dead ends.
And maybe prepare or plan the plan B: new seeds and/or seedlings.
Next year you may think if it would be better to wait some more weeks, or to transplant only few plants so early (just to get early fruits) and wait for the rest of seedlings.
PS: check also the "trunk" so the bottom part. Snails and rats can cause similar damages (and hot weather may have trigged them).

A cold snap took the last survivors :'-(.  The next generation is in my grow tent now.
I won't get a harvest out of them but I still want the practice for next year.  Thank you for the advice!

I want to thank you again, an unseasonably warm October and November here let me get a small harvest in the end!  https://i.sstatic.net/EAC8zeZP.jpg
https://i.sstatic.net/nSqZCcYP.jpg

That to me looks like symptoms of squash vine borer. I had lost all of my pumpkins to them, make sure no larvae are in those vines and kill them. Other than that, when a squash reaches that point, it would be best to leave it to nature, it will most likely die from limited growth.

You are right, it does look a lot like squash vine borer.  It is too soon for those where I live, though and I can confirm my vines are currently 100% pest free.  Based on their history I am almost certain it is cold damage from neglected hardening.
